# Issue with Transaction in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a servlet code which is using Hibernate for the database transactions. Now, I have code like,

```
tx = session.beginTransaction();

// codes

session.save();
tx.commit();
```

Now, I want to lock the table (lock for both read and write) while the transaction codes is executing. Can anybody help me how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following piece of code

```
   LockOptions lockOptions = new LoackOptions();
   lockOptions.setLockMode(LockMode.READ);
   lockOptions.setTimeOut(2000);  // number of milliseconds     
   lockOptions.setScope(false);  // set this is to true of you want cascading of the lock to associations. 
   session.buildLockRequest().lock(objectTobeLocked);
```

Click [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/LockMode.html) for other options of LockMode
Hope this helps.